# Excel data reconciliation Find values in list that sum to another total

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have excel spreadsheet with large column of numbers (+/- account balances). I have a known reconciliation break value. I need to find combinations of values from 1st column that total the reconciliation break within a tolerance / margin of error.

Current process involves manual work and intuition of system users

```
Settle Date Transactions        DAY C3
16/07/2019  87,141.67       16/07/2019  723,135,655.87
16/07/2019  12,953,790.93           
16/07/2019  1,943,740.50            
16/07/2019  7,893,512.07            
16/07/2019  349,221.79          
16/07/2019  106,241.71          
16/07/2019  48,091,394.72           
16/07/2019  3,070,829.63            
16/07/2019  53,116.69           
16/07/2019  63,278.60           
16/07/2019  2,692,914.80            
16/07/2019  39,264.66           
16/07/2019  3,438.70            
16/07/2019  119,087,174.66          
16/07/2019  4,582,306.12            
16/07/2019  1,642,923.99            
16/07/2019  1,007,106.28            
16/07/2019  5,121,491.32            
16/07/2019  1,289,143.77            
16/07/2019  5,289,561.44            
16/07/2019  145,547,793.17          
16/07/2019  1,089,914.05            
16/07/2019  2,147,341.57            
16/07/2019  1,176,688.83            
16/07/2019  28,166,627.90           
16/07/2019  1,606,566.24            
16/07/2019  831,080.20          
16/07/2019  393,669.57          
16/07/2019  4,301,602.19            
16/07/2019  125,985.34          
16/07/2019  781,759.65          
16/07/2019  740,098         
16/07/2019  402,267.41          
16/07/2019  683,589.14          
16/07/2019  106,526.16          
16/07/2019  246,291.30          
16/07/2019  255,066.16          
16/07/2019  940,640.73          
16/07/2019  197,445.42          
16/07/2019  288,279.89          
16/07/2019  328,797.31          
16/07/2019  109,010,672.56          
16/07/2019  2,098,116.87            
16/07/2019  10,563.40           
16/07/2019  174,558.89          
16/07/2019  2,845,886.64            
16/07/2019  1,145,237.86            
16/07/2019  11,908.13           
16/07/2019  77,618.28           
16/07/2019  309,602.18          
16/07/2019  139,695.91          
16/07/2019  8,477.45            
16/07/2019  805,403.44          
16/07/2019  121,595,195.58          
16/07/2019  35,186,188.65           
16/07/2019  94,883,506.91           
16/07/2019  275,119.52          
16/07/2019  14,577,431.76           
16/07/2019  201,126.99          
16/07/2019  1,511,220.08            
16/07/2019  19,954,610.36           
16/07/2019  16,456,478.06           
16/07/2019  19,029,785.73           
16/07/2019  34,697,800.16           
16/07/2019  59,749,626.78           
16/07/2019  182,810,552.21          
16/07/2019  8,557,663.15            
16/07/2019  3,179,506.59            
16/07/2019  88,943.23           
16/07/2019  1,319,497.11            
16/07/2019  1,032,256.50            
16/07/2019  1,182,816.53            
16/07/2019  31,744.86           
16/07/2019  264,116.50          
16/07/2019  196,158.80          
16/07/2019  695,589.13          
16/07/2019  35,956.10           
16/07/2019  3,114,434.86            
16/07/2019  585,379.44          
16/07/2019  1,029,662.33            
16/07/2019  1,833,969.54            
16/07/2019  3,104,075.39            
16/07/2019  2,719,352.73            
16/07/2019  173,199,280.61          
16/07/2019  1,493,027.58            
16/07/2019  344,406.59          
16/07/2019  3,311,324.70            
16/07/2019  2,340,935.28
```

Is there a way to calculate the values from column 2 that total 723,135,655.87

I can see code in previous examples for Python but I need to do this in Excel

Comment: Maybe you can start here: [How To Find All Combinations That Equal A Given Sum In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3557-excel-find-all-combinations-that-equal-given-sum.html).

Comment: An answer to you question is available at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)